# A file server and its associated clients

Tags: c, linux, sockets, fileserver

I am extremely new to socket programming and I am implementaing a file server that receives request like open(), read(), write(), close() from clients. The file server will process the requests and send the clients the return value of each system call.

I don't know what type of socket I need to define(i.e. stream socket, datagram socket etc). and what command will send the request from the client, how will I receive the return value from the server, how will I receive it at the server end and send the return value to my client.

Will be gratefull to get some pointers.

Thanks

An edit: Is something simple like this work for starting [Server not able to properly read/open a filename sent by client in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356201/server-not-able-to-properly-read-open-a-filename-sent-by-client-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends in part upon your file server design.

If you're going for a [stateless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_server) server, then datagram or stream would be fine. Datagram is relatively nice because your servers and clients don't need to handle *partial* requests -- the entire contents of the request are contained in the datagram.

If you're going for a [stateful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful) server, then stream might be nicer -- you can automatically release locks and de-allocate resources 'owned' by a client when you receive a TCP `RST` packet. (Client gone, throw away their state.) You could of course build a stateful server with datagram services, but it doesn't seem like a good fit.

But on the open Internet, typically you have just [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) and [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) -- I have no idea if [RDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol), a reliable datagram transport, is routed on given ISPs or not. And being forced between *unreliable* datagrams and *reliable* streams, I'd recommend reliable streams almost every time. Will your use your protocol on reliable LANs only? Or on lossy wireless or public Internet links?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a streaming socket, but others have done differently, for example the Network File System (NFS).

To communicate between a client and the server you need a *protocol*. The one that OpenSSH uses for their `scp` and `sftp` programs is nice to implement. Have a look at it. http://openssh.org/txt/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02.txt

Comment: Note that more recent versions of [NFS have moved to TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System_(protocol)).

Comment: and @sarnold Is it possible to get a rough sample code so that I am more clear. Thanks for the trouble

Comment: I don't have any sample code, but — once again — look at the `scp` and `sftp` programs from OpenSSH.